# pupulating/fill spinner with retrofill2 after callback process

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-spinner

I'm attempting to populating/fill Spinner with retrofit2, but this ever give me error or return object null . (Error message: https://pastebin.com/V4N5S3ih  ) 
heres my code:

```
public String[] dat;
getAkun.getAkunUserKategori("jan","pemasukan", new Akun_Get.dataCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void getData(List<tblAkunDatabase> value) {
            result = value;

            if(result.size() > 0)
            {


                dat = new String[result.size()];
                for(int i = 0;i< result.size();i++)
                {
                    dat[i] = String.valueOf(result.get(i).getKdAkun());

                }


            }
            else
            {
                dat = new String[1];
                dat[0] = "Empty";
                AllData(dat);

            }
        }

    });

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dat);
    spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

that's the part of my code, Thank you

UPDATE

```
getAkun.getAkunUserKategori("jan","pemasukan", new Akun_Get.dataCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void getData(List<tblAkunDatabase> value) {
            result = value;

            if(result.size() > 0)
            {


                dat = new String[result.size()];
                for(int i = 0;i< result.size();i++)
                {
                    dat[i] = String.valueOf(result.get(i).getKdAkun());

                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Input_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dat);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            else
            {
                dat = new String[1];
                dat[0] = "Empty";

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Input_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dat);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    });
```

I try to put arrayadapter in callback process but I got annother error message: https://pastebin.com/ahZ2RnCg

Comment: i am unable to see your logcat image, will please share error logcat here.?

Comment: @HemantParmar  Sorry sir, I think I've found the clue of my problem. Thank You for your time and kindness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 
finally, I fount the clue:

```
getAkun.getAkunUserKategori("jan","pemasukan", new Akun_Get.dataCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void getData(List<tblAkunDatabase> value) {
            result = value;

            if(result.size() > 0)
            {

                dat = new String[result.size()];
                for(int i = 0;i< result.size();i++)
                {
                    dat[i] = String.valueOf(result.get(i).getKdAkun());
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Input_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dat);
                    spin.setAdapter(adapter);

                }



            }
            else
            {
                dat = new String[1];
                dat[0] = "Empty";

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Input_Jurnal.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, dat);
                spin.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    });
```

so, I put ArrayAdaptor and Spinner widget into a itteration on callback